# Выборка дочернего элемента jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Есть следующий код:

```js
$('.unit').each(function(){
  //...
});
```

Как получить дочерний элемент this с классом "callsign"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.unit').each(function(){
  $(this).find('.callsign')...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.unit').each(function(){
  $(this).children('.callsign')...
});
```